# Стоит ли использовать Function?

Tags: javascript, функции

*Сразу говорю, мне это не нужно для выполнения каких-либо задач, поэтому не нужно ничего говорить про "ошибку молотка"*

Чем `Function()` отличается от `eval` (в плане обработки кода)? И является ли более безопасным?

Comment: Ну так объект `Function` создает только функцию переменная которой будет названием функции, а `eval` - выполняет любой скрип-код.

Comment: Принципиальной разницы нет, `(new Function('', userInput))()` - тот же eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основное отличие, в том, что при прямом вызове `eval` есть доступ к локальным переменным, в то время как при использовании `Function` доступ только к глобальному контексту.

Пример:

```js
var a = 'outer';

function A() {
  var a = 'inner';

  var fun = new Function('', 'return a;');
  var ev = eval('a'); // прямой вызов
  var ev2 = (0,eval)('a'); // непрямой вызов
  console.log(fun(), ev,ev2);
}

A();
```